# HK: May I stay in the transit area to get the earliest airport ferry to Macao on the day after arrival?

Tags: airports, ferries, hong-kong, macau

My flight is landing at 20.40, so I can't get the last ferry on the same day. Plus I do not have HK entry visa.
Can I wait in the transit area till the next day to take the first airport ferry to Macao?

Comment: [According to the information here](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/transport-connection-with-mainland-china/ferry-transfer/passengers-transiting-to-prd-ports.html), one of the requirements for a 'transit service' is to posses a *"**same day** arrival flight air ticket / e-ticket / boarding pass stub"*

Comment: That being said, nationals of about 170 countries and territories may visit Hong Kong without a visa/entry permit for a period ranging from 7 days to 180 days. What nationality/passport will you be travelling under?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently not, the website [explicitly lists this among the requirements](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/transport/transport-connection-with-mainland-china/ferry-transfer/passengers-transiting-to-prd-ports.html):

> - Same day arrival flight air ticket / e-ticket / boarding pass stub;
>
> […]
>
> - Transfer to PRD / Macao within the same day of arrivals;